# Generate pdf report from dataframe and charts using Jinja2 and pdfkit in streamlit

Tags: python, jinja2, report, pdf-generation, streamlit

I developed an app that reads csv files and then provides the user with a summary of data in the form of a dataframe and a chart. I would like to provide the user with the option of downloading these results in a pdf format. I found these code examples to be helpful:
https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-pdf-reports-with-python-pdfkit-and-jinja2-templates-64a89158fa2d
https://github.com/lcalmbach/report-generator-for-long-tables/tree/main

However, when I tried to follow these guides, I ended up with the following error
" TemplateNotFound"

A minimum Python code example:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pdfkit
import jinja2

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("", accept_multiple_files=False) 
df= pd.read_csv(uploaded_file[0])

TEMPLATE_FILE = "reportTemplate.html"

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
template = templateEnv.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)

outputText = template.render(df=df, month='May')
html_file = open('report.html', 'w')
html_file.write(outputText)
html_file.close()
```

HTML template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Flow Accumulation Report: {{ month }}%</h1> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            {% for column in df.columns %}
            <th>{{ column }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for idx, row in df.iterrows() %}
        <tr>
            {% for colname in df.columns %}
            <td>${{ row[colname] | round(1) }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>    
</body>
```

Folder Structure

App folder contains:

```
-1- app.py
-2- pages folder contains several streamlit pages (e.g., page1.py, page2.py, etc.)
-3- reportTemplate.html
```

Comment: Your code actually works just fine for me. Are you **sure** that there isn't a typo either in the filename of the template itself, the filename for the template in your python script, or possibly that the template isn't in the right directory relative to the execution directory? The error you're seeing is because it *can't find the template*, after all, so you're going to need to figure out why that is, since I can't actually reproduce the error after making my own `reportTemplate.html` & copying your script to run locally.

Answer (score 0):

After manually checking the directory assigned to the template file, I understood the problem. My mistake was that I was asking the code to get the “template.html” file from the pages folder.

I think I better understand now why Flask imposes that the template is always called from its own separate folder. It actually leads to fewer mistakes.

I modified my streamlit code in the following way:

```
pages_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
app_path = os.path.dirname(pages_path)
                    
path=os.path.join(app_path,'./templates')
templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=path)
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
TEMPLATE_FILE = "template.html"
template = templateEnv.get_template( TEMPLATE_FILE )
```